# Gulp source maps not working on remote server

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

So I'm running a gulp setup *(remote server)* which creates source maps in the right directory, adds a sourceMappingURL *(linking to the correct map)* to my css file, and writes the correct sourceRoot in my css.map.

When I check my element styles however, it still keeps pointing towards the compiled css file. *(Instead of the source.scss file)*

Here's my directory structure:

dev - 
|        | 
|        scss - 
|                 | 
|                 main.scss 
prod - 
        | 
        css - 
               | 
                 main.css 
                 main.min.css 
                 main.min.css.map

The source mapping url within my `main.min.css` is: sourceMappingURL=main.min.css.map 
The source root in `main.min.css.map` is: "sourceRoot":"../../dev/scss" 


My gulp function looks as follow:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('site/lvh2016/dev/scss/main.scss', { sourcemap: true, style: 'compact' })
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('site/lvh2016/prod/css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
        includeContent: false,
        sourceRoot:'../../dev/scss'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('site/lvh2016/prod/css'));
});
```

Does anybody have any idea why my page inspector doesn't point me towards the source .scss files? But rather shows the minified .css as source?

Comment: Check if you can access /dev/scss/main.scss in your browser. Scss sources must be accessible by the webserver.

Comment: Checked the scss file, it was accessible. Also checked all the includes within the main.scss, they were also accessible.